# Intermittent "invalid character at 1,1" errors in Visual Studio 2017 project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have a large project I'm testing locally where, intermittently, with no changes to the code, and with no common events, the site will suddenly display massive numbers of "invalid character" errors in basic js libraries like jquery.  If you try to look at said js files in debug in the various browsers, they come up as gibberish as if they were compiled (they aren't)

The site will lose its formatting because of the lost access to various js libraries, and everything will misbehave. Hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> will randomly make it better, worse, or have no effect at all.

Rebuilding the site, resetting IIS, and restarting Visual Studio has no standard result.  The only thing that is true is that after A Period Of Time, with no changes made or unmade to the code, the issue will clear as mysteriously as it arrived. Looking at the js files return to their un-gibberishy format, and all proceeds as if nothing has occurred.

It's a large project, and there are certainly packages and libraries that have updates which we're not in a position to update right now.  It's the intermittent nature of the issue that's the most annoying - it'll happen with no changes made to the code, and fix itself as mysteriously.  It's happening for all users, so it doesn't appear to be any one person's issue.

We're not seeing such a thing happen on out test and production servers, only which running and testing locally.  It'll happen whether or not the VS debugger is on or not.  There's no common trigger that we can find.

Anyone ever heard of something like this?

Comment: Sounds like a very strange IDE issue (hence why it's not happening on test or production). A few questions: What update of Visual Studio 2017 are you using? Are you bundling your js (and if so, what are you using)? What package manager are you using?

Comment: I'm on the latest one that came out this week, don't recall what the release is. We're using bundleconfig for packaging the js files. A handful of packages have been added with nuget, but the majority of files (jQuery, bootstrap, knockout, etc) are likely the ones that came with the initial new project / solution when created. Last time I looked there was something like 60-70 files it said there were updates for, but as mentioned, we don't have the time to regression test that much stuff right now.